# Where to init and how to use controllers and models in MVC pattern in Java application?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am building desktop app and trying to use `MVC pattern`. I want models & controllers to be accessible in  GUI (views), but I need to init all controllers and models in the root of the app. Moreover - I need to pass all of them to my GUI init method and in all child methods.

Is there any simple way to init and call models and controllers in views components? I am currently have 7 models and 7 controllers, but what if in the future there will be more, should I hardcode them, is it ok?

I am actually WEB developer, so I can show as an example Javascript implementations for storage usages. There is frameworks for convinient storage usage for the entire app - React(Redux) Vue(Vuex). They are registered as plugins and accessible in all app, maybe there is something same in java for mvc

```
    import com.base.views.MainWindow;
    import com.base.models.ActionsModel;
    // models...
    import com.base.controllers.ActionsController;
    // controllers...
    
    public class Main {
        ActionsModel actionsModel = new ActionsModel();
        // models...
        ActionsController actionsController= new ActionsController();
        // controllers...
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainWindow viewMainWindow = new MainWindow();
            viewMainWindow.init(actionsModel, actionsController, ....); // I want to use models and controllers in MainWindow (GUI)
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: I suppose that you develop a desktop application and not a web application? (Because in the latter case you might already have found your way to Spring MVC, it's nearly un-avoidable to stumble over that in the web)

Comment: Yes, I am developing desktop app, not web. Web was just for an example. I wanted to know any solutions for desktop

Comment: Especially for a desktop application, why not use  a framework like Spring or Guava that gives you MVC with Dependency Injection out of the box?

Comment: I'd say, register callbacks with the models, as the data in the model changes notify/update the views.